# Why are there so many null mappings in HashMap?

Tags: java, collections

While doing some debugging, I realized that the HashMap's table I use had many empty mappings, why is that ?

For example, the HashMap had a size of 471.189, when it had a `table=HashMap$Entry<K, V>[1048576]`, which is about 2.2 times more than needed.

Comment: Do you know how a hash table works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A theoretical implementation of a [hash table (wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) will create a larger than necessary storage space to reduce the chances of hash collisions. When a key value is added to the hash, a calculation is done (on the `hashCode()` of the key value) to determine where in the hash table the key will be stored. That is what makes the hash table concept fast to use, and the better the hashing and hashing function is, the fewer the collisions are, and the faster the system runs.

The larger the empty space in the hash table, the less chance there is of a collision.

If there is a collision, there is a system in place which allows the values to be stored in a different way, still fast, but not perfect.

The bottom line is that a hash table is a trade off, a compromise, between performance and 'wasted' space.

When you debug, you see the empty space in the HashMap, and that's normal, even 'healthy'.

As the hash table (HashMap) gets filled up, it will 're-map' the data in to a bigger hash table. This remapping can be slow, so, if you know your hash table is going to grow to a particular size, you should probably pre-allocate the space using the [capacity argument on the constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap-int-)